# How do I select every instance of a class on a page, but not the first instance?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I want to set every div with the class="wp-block-column" to 'display:none;' --> but not the first one.

I am having trouble :not selecting the first div with the class="wp-block-column"

BOTTOM LINE: I want to select all divs with the class="wp-block-column" throughout the page regardless of where they land or who their parent is --> but not the first instance. I want to select instances from the body, not a parent div.

`<div class="menu-column">` only appears inside `<div class="seventy-thirty-block">` but there could be 1 or 5 of these blocks, they are generated from a loop.

There could also be any number of blocks that are not `<div class="seventy-thirty-block">`before.

The css on this page works because :not(:nth-child(2) gets the second child of `<div class="singleBlogContent">`

But if I uncomment

```
<!--   

<div class="callout-full-block">
      </div>

  -->
```

then it no longer works because now it's :not(:nth-child(3)

Here is the JS Bin:
https://jsbin.com/xowefaj/edit?html,css,output

The output that I want in the JS Bin is:
content
menu
content
content

This is my html:

```
<div class="singleBlogContent">

  <div class="callout-full-block">
  </div> 

<!--   <div class="callout-full-block">
  </div>  -->
  
  <div class="seventy-thirty-block">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="seventy-thirty-columns">
        <div>
          <div>
            content
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wp-block-column">
          <div class="menu-column">
            menu
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>

  <div class="seventy-thirty-block">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="seventy-thirty-columns">
        <div>
          <div>
            content
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wp-block-column">
          <div class="menu-column">
            menu
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>


  <div class="seventy-thirty-block">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="seventy-thirty-columns">
        <div>
          <div>
            content
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wp-block-column">
          <div class="menu-column">
            menu
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>

</div>
```

This is my css:

```
div.seventy-thirty-block:not(:nth-child(2)) .wp-block-column .menu-column {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you need to add class `container` like so:

```css
.container:not(:nth-of-type(1)) .wp-block-column .menu-column {
    display:none;
}
```

Now it selects sibling divs with the class `container` (being siblings is the key point) but neglects the first one.

Comment: This is helpful, I edited my question to make it more specific. Please look again.

Comment: @TheSendicate When someone answers your question, don't edit your question to ask a different thing. Instead ask a new question. Editing a question with existing answers risks invalidating those answers, which is not allowed here.

Answer (score 0):

Just target them all and then make a more specific rule that targets the first element and give it a display property.

```
.wp-block-column .menu-column {
  display:none;
}

.wp-block-column:first-child .menu-column {
  display:block;
}
```

or looking at your markup it might be the first container you want to target.

```
.container:first-child .wp-block-column .menu-column {
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: This is helpful, I edited my question to make it more specific. Please look again.